# Where is Deploybot pushing my repo to on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, deployment, bitbucket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

This is my setup;

Bitbucket Repo of HTML docs.
Elastic Beanstalk Environment 
EC2 c3 Instance (8GB Elastic Block Store attached)

So I connect Deploybot to Elastic Beanstalk successfully and deploy.  Path is default.

Success, so it seems.

> output Creating application archive for Elastic Beanstalk.
>   output Application archive created.
>   output Uploading application archive to S3 bucket deploybot-elastic-beanstalk-> mysite-997c5d66.
>   output Application archive uploaded.
>   output Creating application version mysite-fbba70de-5e4736.
>   output Application version created.
>   output Updating environment e-txarhpt4wp with new version.
>   output Environment was updated and will now be refreshing.

But no...  where are the files?

I drop in with filezilla (SFTP) and cannot find anywere on the server.

Moreover, my path is actually;
var/www/vhosts/my.site.yay/html/

If I change the path in the Deploybot environment settings - the repo never successfuly deploys, instead all I get is 'bypassed' with every single git push which indicates to me that deploybot is not acutally connecting to anything and thus constantly sees 'no changes'.

Anyone got any clues?

I have spent several hours searching prior to this post and there is almost nothing written about using deploybot with aws besides official deploybot documents.

thanks in advance to those with potential answers

Answer (score 0):

Doh!

I had set up my ec2 instance to use Nginx instead of Apache - deleting Apache (httpd).

In the process of writing this question I looked more closely at the deploybot log and traced that Deploybot pushs a .zip to a **S3 bucket** which it creates and then triggers an elastic beanstalk environment refresh - using whatever built in webhook there must be.

So whatever webhook that uses looks for Apache (httpd) and the whole thing fails, as revealed in the Beanstalk environment event logs;

> ERROR
>   [Instance: i-0dc350d4f82711400] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...tory @ rb_sysopen - /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (Errno::ENOENT) from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/php_apache_env:81:in `update_apache_env_vars' from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/php_apache_env:125:in`' Using configuration value for DocumentRoot:. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/05_configure_php.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

So, I switched my deploybot to SFTP with public key and it works. (I'm not clever enough to edit/write my own beanstalk envior refresh webhook yet)